# significance behind escaping parentheses in expr match

Tags: regular-expression, quoting, expr

Can anybody give me the difference between the following two commands in the context of escaping parentheses, or refer some document that would clear my doubt.

```
string=abcABC123ABCabc

$ echo `expr match "$string" 'abc[A-Z]*.2'` #Result is 8, the count of matched characters

$ echo `expr match "$string" '\(abc[A-Z]*.2\)'`   #Result is abcABC12, the matched characters
```

What is the actual significance of escaped parentheses `\(...\)` here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That refers to GNU [`expr`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#expr-invocation) (part of coreutils) and the `\(` and `\)` are marking a *group* as docmented in *[16.4.1 String expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#String-expressions)*:

> If the match succeeds and regex uses `‘\(’` and `‘\)’`, the : expression returns the part of string that matched the subexpression; otherwise, it returns the number of characters matched.

The documentation refers to *[3 Regular Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)* in `grep` for details.  The *syntax* of regular expressions is [documented](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09) in POSIX:

> Consistent with the whole match being the longest of the leftmost matches, each subpattern, from left to right, shall match the longest possible string. For this purpose, a null string shall be considered to be longer than no match at all. For example, matching the BRE `"\(.*\).*"` against `"abcdef"`, the subexpression `"(\1)"` is "abcdef", and matching the BRE `"\(a*\)*"` against "bc", the subexpression `"(\1)"` is the null string.

POSIX [`expr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html) mentions regular expressions with the `:` operator:

```
expr1 : expr2
```

but goes on to say:

> The use of string arguments **`length`**, **substr**, **index**, or **`match`** produces unspecified results.

so this particular usage appears to be an extension.

The POSIX usage of `:` is documented in detail in the section *[Matching Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html#tag_20_42_13_01)*; the **match** operator seen here corresponds to the `:`, but its *position* is changed to an *prefix* operator (before the two operators) where POSIX `:` uses *infix* (between the two operands).

Viewed as a group, the **length**, etc., can be considered either as an *extension* (a nonstandard feature providing functionality not achievable via a particular utility) or merely *nonstandard* (an incompatible way of performing a function which can be done via a different method).  This one is mixed: the POSIX shell gives similar functionality for **length**, etc., as documented in the section on [Parameter Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), i.e., `${#parameter}`.  However **substr** and **index** have no apparent exact equivalent.  (Although the syntax differs, the entire group is probably based on [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)).

Comment: The capture group matched in `expr` is also specified by POSIX, it's not GNUism.

Comment: I was aware of that, but offhand did not recall this case - will clarify further as as needed.

Comment: Note that those length/match are mentioned as allowed extensions for applications to be able to guard against things like `expr length = "$var"` which is not guaranteed to work with every implementation. `length "$var"` can be implemented with `"$var" : '.*'`. `substr` and `index` can also be implemented with the `:` operator. In any case, all those are broken and `expr` should probably be avoided as they fail with some values or have unwanted side effects.

Comment: (a) I was not advising for/against the usage, but explaining it, and (b) I don't see the particular wording in POSIX regarding "allowed extensions").  POSIX is never explicit enough.

Comment: That was just a note, not a critic on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

When the pattern contain the subexpression `\(...\)`, the string matched will be return. This behavior is [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html#tag_20_42_13_01):

> Alternatively, if the pattern contains at least one regular expression
>   subexpression "[\(...\)]", the string matched by the back-reference
>   expression "\1" shall be returned. If the back-reference expression
>   "\1" does not match, then the null string shall be returned.

Note that you should change the command to:

```
expr "$string" : '\(abc[A-Z]*.2\)'
```

to make it work in all POSIX compliant `expr`. The use of `match` is unspecified.

Comment: More like `LC_ALL=C expr "x$string" : 'x\(abc[A-Z]*.2\)'`

Answer (score 0):

Backslashed parentheses `\(...\)` create a "capture group". `expr match` seems to return the first capture group.